# Riesz Lemma with $\alpha=1$ and Linear Bounded Functional

Tags: functional-analysis

Show that on a normed linear space $X$, [Riesz lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma#The_result) with $\alpha=1 $ holds implies that every bounded linear functional attains its norm on the unit sphere of $X$.

This is not a homework question and I have tried a huge amount of approaches (too much to describe my attempts in here), so excuse me for not showing my work. A good hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/838662/riesz-lemma-for-reflexive-spaces

Comment: For the other direction, take $f\in X^*$, set $M={\rm ker}\, f$ and use [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253953/distance-between-point-and-linear-space).