# Bounded linear functional attaining its norm on a $\sigma$-finite measure space

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $(X, \mathfrak{M}, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space, let $1 < p < \infty$, and let $T$ be a bounded linear functional
on $L^p(X, \mu).$

I am trying to prove to myself that $T$ attains its norm.

The only thing that is coming to mind that we would need to show that for any $x \in X$, $$||Tx|| \leq ||T|| \: ||x|| \text{  and  } ||Tx|| \geq ||T|| \: ||x||$$

Help would be appreciated.

---

I would like to use Mason's suggestion to reduce the problem down to:

Given $f \in L^q,$ find $g \in L^p$ with $||g||_p = 1$ such that $|\int gf| = ||f||_q$

Your thoughts would be appreciated

Comment: Just for fun, one can prove what is known as James’ theorem: $X$ is reflexive if and only if every element of $X’$ attains its norm. As a corollary your claim would follow.

Comment: Interesting! Ill have to look into that at some point. I would rather have this proven directly at this point though

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153473/continuous-linear-functional-on-a-reflexive-banach-space-attains-its-norm?rq=1) may help. (Maybe there is a simpler proof for your specific space.)

Comment: Thank you for that. Just from first glance it appears to be a bit over my head in regards to what I'm looking for. If you think of something simpler for my case please do share.

Comment: @AnIsomorphicTeen I think you have to use the fact that $L^{q}$ is the dual space of $L^p$, where $q$ is the conjugate exponent to $p$. Now the problem reduces to "given $f \in L^q$, find $g \in L^p$ with $\|g\|_p = 1$ such that $|\int gf| = \|f\|_q$.

Comment: Interesting. Do you think the Riez representation theorem for the dual of $L^p$ can come into play at all?

Comment: If you put $\ f=e^{i\theta}|f|\ $, with $\ \theta:X\rightarrow(-\pi,\pi]\ $, and
$$
g=e^{-i\theta}\left|\frac{f}{\|f\|_q}\right|^\frac{1}{p-1}
$$
then $\ g\in L^p\ $ with $\ \|g\|_p=1\ $ and $\ \int fg =\|f\|_q\ $.

Comment: Does this work for any $f$?

Comment: Okay thank you. If you could formalize this as a canonical answer so that I may accept the answer and give the bounty that would be very helpful.

Comment: It'll be a little while before I'll be able to do that but I'll do it in a day or so if nobody else beats me to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\ L^q\ $ is the dual of $\ L^p\ $, where $\ q=\frac{p}{p-1}\ $, then there exists $\ f_T\in L^q\ $ such that $\ Tx=\int_\limits{X}f_Tx\,d\mu\ $ for all $\ x\in L^p\ $.  By the [Hölder inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality), therefore, $\ |Tx|\le\|f_T\|_q\,\|x\|_p\ $, and it follows that $\ \|T\| \le\|f_T\|_q\ $.

Now let $\ u=\frac{f_T}{|f_T|}\ $ and
$$
g=u^{-1}\left|\frac{|f_T|}{
\|f_T\|_q}\right|^\frac{1}{p-1}\ .
$$
Then
\begin{align}
\int_X|g|^p\,d\mu&=\int_X\frac{|f_T|^q}{\|f_T\|_q^q}\,d\mu\\
&=1\ ,
\end{align}
so $\ g\ $ lies in the unit ball of $\ L^p\ $.  But
\begin{align}
Tg&=\int_Xf_Tg\,d\mu\\
&=\int_X\frac{|f_T|^{1+\frac{1}{p-1}}}{\|f_T\|_q^ \frac{1}{p-1}}\,d\mu\\
&=\frac{\|f_T\|_q^q}{\|f_T\|_q^ \frac{1}{p-1}}\\
&=\|f_T\|_q\ .
\end{align}
It follows that $\ \|T\|= \|f_T\|_q
 $ and $\ Tg=\|T\|\ $.